# C# concurrency problem with ADO.NET and trigger explicit disabling

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I was investigating a strange issue happening in my multi-threaded C# application, causing wrong results returned from my underlying SQL server database, accessed through ADO.NET

Here how I get the results from the db

```
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            tubes.Add(MapDBRowToTube(row));
        }
    }
}
```

Each thread has its own SqlConnection / SqlTransaction.

I have to say I didn't write the SQL programming but I discovered that table "A" (the one that gives problematic results) has a trigger on it, that in turn updates a table "B". B has a trigger that explicitly disables/enables the trigger on table A (I think as an attempt to stop indirect recursion).

```
   -- code inside trigger B
    BEGIN TRAN;
    
    DISABLE TRIGGER [trName] ON A
    UPDATE A SET [..]
    FROM Inserted
    WHERE [...]

    ENABLE TRIGGER [trName] ON A
    COMMIT
```

This explicit "DISABLE/ENABLE trigger" results in strange concurrency problems, I have no exceptions from the code itself, but the retrieved data is the one from another thread. If I just comment out DISABLE / ENABLE triggers instructions, everything works fine.

To replicate my problem I simply pre-loaded a list of A, and while loading each A item one at a time from the db, I compared the original with the current. Meanwhile I updated in a not committed transaction A, just to fire the trigger.

Does anyone has an explanation for this? Hope my description is clear enough

Comment: Enabling, and disabling, a trigger inside a `TRIGGER` seems like a design flaw, if I am honest. A trigger that results in another trigger firing, that could cause the original trigger to fire again is certainly a design flaw; that could easily result in infinite recursion. Certainly "Trigger B" should not be calling back to the object that "trigger A" belongs to. What ever logic these triggers are doing, it seems like it *shouldn't* be inside the trigger or they need significant rewriting.

Comment: To be honest I would limit the usage of triggers only to certain borders. My idea is that who wrote this just abused of them to put in place a sort of "hot fix". Anyway what surprise me a lot is how it could give such concurrency problems. Also the fact that DISABLE/ENABLED are wrapped in an explicit transaction lead me to think they should be "isolated"

Comment: Transactions inside a trigger are completely pointless. A trigger is already inside a transaction, the one the DML operation is using, and nested transactions in SQL Server are a myth. You should never be declaring explicit transactions inside a trigger. At best, it'll do nothing, at worst, unexpected behaviour. If you want a trigger to cause a transaction to rollback, then it should `THROW` an error with a high enough severity to cause the calling DML statement to fail and rollback automatically (or go to its own `CATCH` where an explicit `ROLLBACK` is most likely defined).

Comment: It seems they're doing nothing because commenting out just the transaction declarations has no impacts at all :) Thanks for your support